# How to stop Access from prompting "Do you want to save changes to the layout of query"

Tags: vba, ms-access

#### How can I stop Access from prompting "Do you want to save changes to the layout of query" when I try to close a form that has a subform in datasheet view?

I have a form with a subform in Datasheet view with the `.SourceObject` set to a temporary **pivot / crosstab** query (no actual form object).  If the user *changes the width of a column* and closes the window with the built-in Access close button, the user (and annoyed developer) is always presented with the "Do you want to save changes to the layout of query" prompt.

[image]

I am able to avoid this prompt by setting `MySubform.SourceObject = ""` in the click of *my* Close button but anyone clicking the [x] button or pressing CTRL+F4 or CTRL+W gets the prompt.

I have put breakpoints in the `Form_Close` and `Form_Unload` events but this prompt appears before they fire.

I want to clarify further that this subform object is Unbound and not based on a form object.  I am building a dynamic Crosstab SQL statement, creating a QueryDef with the SQL, and then setting `MySubform.SourceObject = "query.qry_tmp_Pivot"`  This is a neat technique for a crosstab/pivot query because the columns can vary and I don't think a form object would support that.

I am able to use the Watch window on the MySubform object and I can see that a `MySubform.Form` object exists.  It has a Controls collection containing a control for all of the columns in my query.  I have an optional routine that I can run that will loop through all of the controls and set their `.ColumnWidth = -2`, which will auto-size the column width based on the widest data of the visible rows in the datasheet.  When this routine was running I was noticing that every time I closed the form (not using my Close button) I was getting the save prompt.  I have disabled this routine for debugging but a user will still get the prompt if they manually adjust any column width.

I feel like I need to explain this extra detail so you realize this is not an Access 101 issue.  You probably know that if you've read this far.  Here's another thought I had:  *Maybe I could trap the Unload event in the subform control before the prompt happens.*  Because there is no true Form object to put test code in, I created a class object and passed MySubform to it.  The class uses `WithEvents` and creates events like `OnClose` and `OnCurrent` on the class module's mForm object.  Sample class code is below.

```vb
Private WithEvents mForm As Access.Form  ' This is the form object of the Subform control

Public Sub InitalizeSubform(Subform As Access.Subform)

    Set mForm = Subform.Form
    Debug.Print Subform.Name, mForm.Name, mForm.Controls.count
    
    ' Create some events to intercept the default events.
    mForm.OnClick = "[Event Procedure]"
    mForm.OnClose = "[Event Procedure]"
    mForm.OnUnload = "[Event Procedure]"
    mForm.OnCurrent = "[Event Procedure]"

End Sub

Private Sub mForm_Click()
    Debug.Print "Clicking " & mForm.Name
End Sub

Private Sub mForm_Current()
    Debug.Print "On Current " & mForm.Name, "Record " & mForm.CurrentRecord & " of " & mForm.RecordsetClone.RecordCount
End Sub

Private Sub mForm_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    Debug.Print "Unloading " & mForm.Name
End Sub

Private Sub mForm_Close()
    Debug.Print "Closing " & mForm.Name
End Sub
```

The VBE Watch window shows my new events on the mForm object but unfortunately they never fire.  I know the class works because I used it with a bound subform and all of the events are intercepted by the class.  I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: Can disable X close with form properties and trap Ctrl+key combinations with an AutoKeys macro. Is right click menu Close also an issue? There are ways to stabilize a CROSSTAB query so the field names will be same each time.

Comment: If your class works with a bound form, why not write the output of the crosstab to a temp table and bind a subform to this? Slightly clumsy, but if it works ... and that dialogue box _is_ disturbing.

Comment: What about **[DoCmd.SetWarnings method (Access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.setwarnings)**? Maybe it can help you out, but test it

Comment: @June7, I don't want to go down the path to disable [x] and trap key combinations.  My Crosstab query can have different columns each time it runs so I am dynamically creating the `IN ()` list to append to the PIVOT statement.---
@foxfireandburnsandburns, I don't think that will help.  I don't want to turn off warnings for the entire operation of the form.  I just need to disable them when the form closes, which is where I'm having trouble finding an event to capture it.

Comment: @Gustav, I tried out your idea to bind to a temp table.  Unfortunately if I change the width or sort of a column I'm getting the save prompt, though now for the temp table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events on the subform never fire because it's a lightweight form (without a module). See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51855653/7296893) and the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.hasmodule). Lightweight forms don't support event listeners, but do support calling public functions from an event, e.g. `mForm.OnClick = "SomePublicFunction()"`

Note that the workaround described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51872306/7296893) also opens up the possibility of displaying a crosstab query in a form without saving it at all.

Alternatively, you could try capturing the event on your main form, and suppress saving there.

Comment: This is the kind of extra help I was looking for.  After setting the `.SourceObject` property of my subform from a button on my main form, I was able to set `.Form.OnCurrent = "=SomePublicFunction()"` *(note the = is required before the function name)*.  After I verified that it was firing for OnCurrent, I added the function to a variety of events: OnUnload, OnLostFocus, OnClose, OnDeactivate.  Unfortunately none of them would fire before the save prompt if I closed the parent form with the [x].  I also tried to capture the event on the main form and still the save prompt happens first. :(

Comment: I recommend the workaround. I developed that specifically to display crosstab queries in subforms, even though the shared version only does tables. I can share the adapted version that works with SQL queries/recordsets

Comment: Your workaround was clearly written and easy to implement so I gave you credit even though I posted an answer.  I hope this is acceptable conduct on SO.  I didn't have any trouble assigning the `.Recordset` to a query instead of a table.  I'm not getting errors.  Is there something I should look out for?

Comment: One thing: if you decide to use a temporary querydef instead of a stored query and parameters in your crosstab query, Access will hard-crash upon filtering/sorting from the top menu (no VBA error but an irrecoverable crash which might leave your database in an inconsistent state). It's the only case where I advocate using string concatenation. But I see you're using a stored query, so that's not an issue for your current implementation

Comment: Good tip.  For anyone else reading this, a temporary QueryDef is one that is defined with no name.  More info at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-createquerydef-method-dao)

Answer (score 1):

I gave answer credit to @ErikA for this question. He directed me to an answer to a somewhat related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51872306/1898524) which is what I ended up implementing and it works.  His instructions were very straightforward and easier to implement than I first anticipated.

***The answer*** to my question seems to be that it may not be possible to avoid the save prompt when using a lightweight form object.  If someone comes along with a solution I'd still like to hear it.

What I learned from this experience:

- An unbound subform that has its `.SourceObject` set to a table or query will not have a code module.  This considered to be a **lightweight object**.
- Public functions can be added to event properties on lightweight forms but they don't seem to fire before the save prompt appears as the parent form is closing.
- Binding a pivot query or temp table to a real form object that has 254 controls on it is the only way I found that doesn't prompt to save design changes when the parent form closes.  Mapping the query/table columns to the 254 datasheet controls is super fast.
- A class is a nice way to intercept events if you're *not* using a lightweight object.  A class also lets you open multiple instances of the same object.
- I ended up not implementing my solution without using a class because there were no events I needed to capture.  At this point I don't need my frmDynDS to be used for other purposes and I'd like to keep the object count down (this is a large app with 1400+ objects).

I put the following code in a function that gets called when the subform is loaded or refreshed.

```
With subCrosstab
    ' Set the subform source object to the special Dynamic Datasheet form.  This could be set at design time on the Subform control.
    .SourceObject = "Form.frmDynDS"
    ' Run the code to assign the form controls to the Recordset columns.
    .Form.LoadTable "qry_tmp_Pivot" ' A query object works as well as a table.

    ' Optional code
    .Form.OnCurrent = "=SomePublicFunction()"
    .Form.AllowAdditions = False
    .Form.AllowEdits = False
    .Form.AllowDeletions = False
    .Form.DatasheetFontHeight = 9   
End With
```

I can now resize the columns and never get a prompt to save layout changes no matter how I close the parent form.